# MySQL optimizing join of 2 large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I know this question has been asked numerous times before, but I have tried the solutions mentioned there and have not found an answer.
I'm not sure whether the answer is simply "it's not possible" and hence decided to ask the question.

I have 2 tables with the following sizes:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from t1
24mill

SELECT COUNT(*) from t1 WHERE col1 = 1 and col2 = 'A';
395k

SELECT COUNT(*) from t2
6mill

SELECT COUNT(*) from t2 WHERE col3 != 'B';
5.9mill
```

Note:

- `col2` and `col3` are enums with only 6 unique values.
- `col1` is a foreign key with ~9000 unique values
- `t1` -> `t2` is a one-to-many => multiple records in `t1` will be linked to the same `t2`.
- None of these columns are nullable

The query I am trying to do is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t2_ID = t2.t2_ID
WHERE t1.col1 = 1 AND t1.col2 = 'A' AND t2.col3 != 'B';
395k
```

`t2_ID` is the Primary Key for t2, and a foreign key in t1.

I have created the index:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD KEY key1 (t2_id);
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD KEY key2 (col1, t2_id, col2);
```

EXPLAIN:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: key1,key2
          key: key2
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 660k
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,key3,key4
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: t1.t2_ID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 85.71
        Extra: Using where
```

When I run this query, it takes 3seconds. I am trying to figure out how I can make this faster.

As I see it, it is already using the index. I'm trying to see if I can make a better index or subqueries or something else to make it faster.

Comment: Face it, crawling through 395K rows takes times.  3 seconds sounds fast.

Comment: Sad, but possibly true. I'd love to understand the reason/cause for the 3sec though. In the sense - what infrastructure parameters should I be looking to improve in such cases. Can I understand how much time of the 3sec is because of data loading (i.e. would a high IOPS disk from Amazon help?) or is it simply RAM cycles (memory optimized instances) or maybe it's just CPU - or all! If no software solution works, I would probably have to go towards hardware optimization

Comment: What version of MySQL?  I think newer versions can make _some_ use of `!=` (but not in the order you have used for the indexes).

Comment: 5.7 - I can go upto the latest minor version. I have to use 5.x due to a bunch of reasons. I am currently using 5.7.26 on a Mac OSX

Comment: @RickJames Why would the `WHERE` clause happen before the join condition?

Comment: Disk drives are not instantaneous.  Even RAM is not instantaneous.  The overhead of fetching 395K rows (of a table or of an index) is not instantaneous.  These are basic principles of computers.  We can discuss whether one index might bring it down to 2 seconds, but don't expect miracles.  Instead, reconsider _why you need that many rows all at once_.

Comment: @RickJames I understand, the reason I ask this is when I try with a 32G RAM, 16core CPU, SSD with Amazon - the query does run within 0.8sec (on a warm start). So, there does seem to be some room for speedups. As to the why - these are events that are captured at various times, and I'm trying to get a summary of the events for a dashboard. I do realize there are summary tables etc. I could create using triggers or manually as events come in - trying to avoid those as the application I am working on is old, and less changes the better (as of now)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Almost always, MySQL uses "NLJ" (Nested Loop Join).  First it looks at one table (filtering out the rows it does not need).  Then for each of those rows, it reaches into the next table.  (Which table comes first is an optimization.)

Comment: @AbdealiJK - OK, maybe 0.8s is a reasonable time.  What differences are there between Amazon's machine and the 3s machine?  Multi-core won't matter.  SSD will matter _if_ the data is not cached in RAM.  But, without knowing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and the index size, I can't say much here.

Comment: I see, understood - that helps. the buffer pool size on my dev machine is 2G, the number on the amazon is 25G - so, that definitely helps ^_^ Was not sure if there are other parameters to consider

Comment: Agreed number of CPU cores does not matter, because a given MySQL query uses only one thread regardless. A _faster_ CPU would give benefit. And it would also be important to fit the data you need to examine in the buffer pool (in RAM), so you avoid reading from storage. SSD is faster than old rotational storage devices, but both are orders of magnitude slower than RAM. And as Rick says, even RAM is not infinitely fast.

Answer (score 2):

The conditions of the `WHERE` clause are more important for row restriction, so the query will examine fewer rows from `t1`. You should index `col1`, `col2` first in the index, so it will narrow down the search more precisely. Then add `t2_id` as a third column of the index.

```
CREATE INDEX keyBK1 ON t1 (col1, col2, t2_id);
```

You may also avoid the join to `t2`'s primary key and join directly to a secondary index, if the first column of the index is `t2_id` and the second column helps to narrow down the search.

```
CREATE INDEX keyBK2 ON t2 (t2_id, col3);
```

I haven't tested it, but I expect the EXPLAIN to be something like the following (which I have mocked up, I didn't actually run EXPLAIN):

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: key1,key2,keyBK1
          key: key3
      key_len: 8
          ref: const,const
         rows: ...about 300k... 
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,key3,key4,keyBK2
          key: keyBK2
      key_len: 8
          ref: t1.t2_ID,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

If you can get both tables to report "Using index" it should be faster.

But this query is always going to be pretty expensive (i.e. slow) if the search on your `t1` table continues to match 300k rows!

Comment: I created the first index, and tried to run it - still took 3sec (EXPLAIN showed that it did not use the new index). But when I did a `USE INDEX(keyBK1)` - it showed the rows to be 830k instead of 300k. I didn't try the second index - because even when Tim suggested it, the index didn't get used

Comment: @AbdealiJK - 830K as the result?  Or 830K in the `EXPLAIN`?

Comment: in the explain - result is the same

Comment: @AbdealiJK - `EXPLAIN` is often imprecise, sometimes by that much.  Take its numbers with a grain of salt.

Comment: If the query is not using the new indexes by itself, you may need to coerce it to do so. Either drop the indexes that are confusing it, or else use index hints. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from t2 where
    t2.col3!='B'
    and not exists( select 1 from t1 where t1.t2_ID = t2.t2_ID and 
                    t1.col1 = 1 AND t1.col2 = 'A')
```

The answer will be the same.

Comment: Hi Yury, using the "not exist" gave me the reverse - So, I think you meant "exist". Using "exist" makes it 20sec

Comment: Yes, exists of course.
Try please: 
select count(*) from t2 where
    t2.col3!='B' and 
    t2.t2_ID in ( select t1.t2_ID from t1 where t1.col1 = 1 AND t1.col2 = 'A')

Comment: Is there a reason you would think these are faster ? My understanding is the IN doesn't use indexes, and so will be slower than a join. The IN takes 9.5sec.
Also, just realized - neither of these give the same results, as there can be 2 records in t1 which are linked to the same record in t1 - it's a one to many

Comment: It looks like you right. One question... Did you try it once only?

Comment: In generally try queries 3 times when testing to understand the impact of buffers/caches within MySQL

Comment: I thought it could be good in first version because it don't need to read t1 table to check existence of the record. The index has all needed fields for this check.

Comment: @Yury - I think this will give the wrong answer.  His query is counting against t1, not t2.

Comment: @AbdealiJK - 3 times == good.  2 times is usually sufficient (and take the second reading).

Comment: @RickJames - I think it must be so, if the query was "Select count(t1_id)..."
but the query is "Select count(*) from t1 inner join t2". Because for one record in t1 exist at least 1 record in t2 (if any), so we count number of records in t2... I think.

Comment: @Yury - but he indicates that there are about 4 rows in t1 corresponding to each row in t2.

Answer (score 0):

`ALTER TABLE t1 ADD KEY key2 (col1, t2_id, col2)` should be changed to:
`ALTER TABLE t1 ADD KEY key2 (t2_id, col1, col2)` to have the column order from most selective to least selective. t2_id has 6m unique values, col1 has 9000 unique values and col2 has 6 unique values. This change will make the index more selective and the query more efficient.

Comment: I think t2_id as the first is not a good idea, because as per the conversation in the comments of the original question - the WHERE will be executed first. So, `col1, col2, t2_id` is the most optimal combination - and here my understanding is that the order of col1, col2 doesnt matter much - because they are both constants

Comment: @AbdealiJK One test is worth a thousand opinions. I stand behind my answer,

Comment: There was an earlier answer by Rick where he suggested the same and had tried it just a while back ... It took 10sec, and there were some discussions on this. Sadly he deleted that answer so the only remnant of that conversation is in the comments in the original question.

Comment: @AbdealiJK Unfortunately no one else can test this out except you because of the size of the data.

Comment: @AbdealiJK I you run this query often then you can keep the index definition with your definition. If this is once in a while query then you should have the index as I have suggested. There is a cost associated with an index on a table in terms of data space, log space and the time it takes to update the index on insert, update and delete. You know your system so you have to make the appropriate decisions.